# @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name not showing backslash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Super Simple. Only issues I find are people getting null. Which I obvi fixed. But where is the backslash???!!

```
params.me = '@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name';
```

This returns

```
"domainUserName" <- Browser
"domain\\UserName" <- Debugging
```

What I expect is

```
"domain\UserName" <- Browser
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what if you get directly as `@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Show us the code you use ti write it in the browser

Comment: @Rahul-alert box no longer shows up. :/ needs those. Was worth a try...

Comment: What about Html.Raw(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)

Comment: @CodeNotFound alert box didn't work. This did show up though alert('@Html.Raw(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)'); But of course no backslash... RRAWAWWWWWRRRR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments you are using the following code to show the user name:

```
alert('@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name');
```

`@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`is a string that can contain "\" backslash character. This character is considered as a escape character in javascript as it is in C# as well.
You need to escape the "\" character in the string before passing it to Javascript like that:

```
alert('@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Replace("\\", "\\\\")')
```